# Using R to parse and return text in parenthesis

Tags: r

Let's say I have a string:

```
x <- "This is a string (Yay, string!)"
```

I'd like to parse the string and return "Yay, string!"

How do I do that?

I tried a bunch of grep/grepl/gsub/sub/etc but couldn't find the right combination of regex or arguments. Sigh. I need to work on the regex skills.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract info inside all parenthesis in R (regex)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613237/extract-info-inside-all-parenthesis-in-r-regex)

Comment: Definitely a dupe, but the answers seem different.

Comment: `strapplyc` in the gsubfn package handles problems like that.  The regular expression in the following code matches `(` followed by any number of characters that are not `)` and returns the part within parentheses:  `library(gsubfn); strapplyc(x, "\\(([^)]*)", simplify = TRUE)`   By default it uses tcl regular expressions which are quite fast, e.g. check the examples in `?strapplyc` for the one which parses the entire text of James Joyce's Ulysses in seconds.  Regarding learning about regex's, there are links to regex resources on the gsubfn home page http://gsubfn.googlecode.com .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing it:

**One:** Find the string you want, and replace the entire string with the bit that was found. (Known as back referencing)

```
gsub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "Yay, string!"
```

This works because:

- You use a backreference `\\1` to refer to the matched string in the parentheses `(.*)`
- Since you want to exclude the parentheses in the actual string, you need to escape these with `\\(` and `\\)`.

---

**Two:** Replace all the bits you don't want with empty strings:

```
gsub(".*\\(|\\).*", "", x)
[1] "Yay, string!"
```

This works because the `|` acts similar to `OR`.

Comment: Is there some documentation for the `\\1` usage? I read about it at the bottom of ?grep but didn't understand it.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I've expanded the answer slightly, but in general my advice is to learn regex from anywhere but the R docs.  For example, here is a [tutorial on backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I've also added the opposite approach, i.e. replacing the bits you don't want with empty strings.

Comment: Appreciate the extra attention here and the link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

Also, if some of your strings might contain several parenthesized substrings, all of which you want to extract, use the regex power-tools `gregexpr()` and `regmatches()`:

```
x <- "This is (a) string (Yay, string!)" 
pat <- "(?<=\\()([^()]*)(?=\\))"
regmatches(x, gregexpr(pat, x, perl=TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"            "Yay, string!"
```

Comment: And just like that, I now see that my **answer** is an exact duplicate of the one referenced a moment ago by Tyler Rinker above!

Comment: That was the basis of the `bracketX` and `bracketXtract` functions in `qdap`. I asked a question that is similar and provides even more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621066/remove-text-inside-brackets-parens-and-or-braces

Comment: I saw that question, but it was far too complex for my limited understanding of regex.

Comment: You mean you don't speak `"(?<=\\()([^()]*)(?=\\))"`? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[qdap version 1.1.0](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/qdap-1-1-0-released-on-cran/) can do this:

```
library(qdap)
x <- "This is a string (Yay, string!)" 

bracketX(x)
bracketXtract(x)
```

Yields:

```
> bracketX(x)
[1] "This is a string"
> bracketXtract(x)
[1] "Yay, string!"
```

Though if you're not doing much of this stuff then getting qdap may be a bit of overkill.

Edit:  With Josh's example...

```
> x <- "This is (a) string (Yay, string!)" 
> bracketX(x)
[1] "This is string"
> bracketXtract(x)
[1] "a"            "Yay, string!"
```