# replace text within parenthesis in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove text inside brackets, parens, and/or braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621066/remove-text-inside-brackets-parens-and-or-braces)

I would like to replace the parenthesis and the text between parenthesis in a large text file.

Example input (content in the text file):

```
Keep me (Remove Me 1). Again keep me (Remove Me 2). Again again keep me (Remove Me 3).
```

Output (content in a new text file):

```
Keep me. Again keep me. Again again keep me.
```

Is it possible to do this in R (say using grep)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, use `gsub()` to replace all the text you don't want with an empty string.

```
x <- "Keep me (Remove Me 1). Again keep me (Remove Me 2). Again again keep me (Remove Me 3)."
```

Here is the regex you want:

```
gsub( " *\\(.*?\\) *", "", x)
[1] "Keep me. Again keep me. Again again keep me."
```

---

It works like this:

- `*?` finds 0 or more spaces before (and after) the parentheses.
- Since `(` and `)` are special symbols in a regex, you need to escape these, i.e. (`\\(`
- The `.*?` is a wildcard find to find all characters, where the `?` means to find in a non-greedy way. This is necessary because regex is greedy by default. In other words, by default the regex will start the match at the first opening parentheses and ends the match at the last closing parentheses.

Comment: +1 @Andrie you are so fast !

Comment: 15 minutes to an answer is hardly fast these days. I only got away with it because it's still thanksgiving holiday and many of the regulars are still eating turkey sandwiches.

Comment: Quick note for people unfamiliar with regex construction: I believe `gsub(glob2rx('(*)'),'',x)`  will do the job.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'd be keen to see if you can make it work with `glob2rx`. I couldn't, and the reason is that `glob2rx` always inserts `^` and `$`. I also couldn't get `glob2rx` to be non-greedy.

Comment: @Andrie thank you so much. I agree you are extremely fast.

Comment: @Andrie, you are correct -- I hadn't considered that problem.  My apologies for not actually testing my code :(  .

Comment: @Andrie, a followup question:  `glob2rx("*.doc",trim.head=TRUE)` returns `"\\.doc$"` , but `glob2rx('(*)',trim.head=TRUE)` returns `[1] "^\\(.*)$"` .  How come the "trim failed" ?   Thanks.